# Accessing SSAS via HTTP

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssas, ssas-2008

I have followed all the steps correctly present in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

I am trying to connect to SSAS 2008 via IIS (HTTP). My SSAS is on Machine 1. My excel 2010 client is on Machine 2. I have enabled basic authentication for this. I am able to connect SSAS when I am using the credentials of 'System Administrator' of Machine 1 (on which SSAS is present). But if I am using any another user then I am able to connect to SSAS. Is this a limitation with IIS or SSAS? Please share your views, it's really urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is resolved. I don't know weather it's a correct solution or not. I have created few users on machine where SSAS is configured with IIS_IUSERS and now SSAS security is working as expected. Please confirm weather it's a right solution or not? Any comments ahd help is appreciated.

With regards,
Avinash Nigam

Comment: SSAS works on windows authentications, and hence users accessing the cube from other machines should to be present in the active directory/domain of the SSAS server. The approach is you used is right approach.

Answer (score 1):

do you have roles defined in the SSAS database granting access to other users?  if "system administrator" is a SSAS server admin, it won't need to be explicity granted access to the SSAS database via a role.  But other users (who are not SSAS server admins) will need explicit access via a role defined in the particular SSAS database.

Comment: Yes, I have role defined in SSAS. My problem is resolved. I don't know weather it's a correct solution or not. I have created few users on machine where SSAS is configured with IIS_IUSERS and now SSAS security is working as expected. Please confirm weather it's a right solution or not? Any comments ahd help is appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need to configure SSAS to be accessed through HTTP to connect to it from excel. Why are you doing that?

Second, the correct way to access a HTTP cube is `http://YOUR_SERVER/olap/msmdpump.dll` if you go to SSMS on machine 2 and inform that on the connection, does it work?

Third and more important, where is IIS? Same box than SSAS? If yes, fine! If no, you need to configure kerberos because you would be dealing with a double hop situation

Comment: When using "Basic Authentication" there is no Kerberos requirement regarless of where IIS and SSAS are physically located.  In fact, I'm guessing the user is using HTTP "Basic" authentication specifically to avoid having to configure Kerberos.

Comment: My understanding of IIS-authentication is very limited. Please correct me if I am wrong, as per my knowledge kerberos and NTLM configuration is required for windows authentication not for basic authentication. Is this correct?